# Can't add Git repository to ArgoCD running in VM

Tags: git, kubernetes, virtualbox, argocd

I have k3s cluster setup in VirtualBox. I have installed ArgoCD and able to login. However, I am unable adding any git repositories nor https neither ssh accessed.
Even public one with no credentials for access is failing to be added.

The fail reason it gives me (repository from ArgoCD tutorial):

```
Unable to connect to repository: 
rpc error: 
code = Unknown 
desc = error testing repository 
connectivity: 
Get "https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/argocd-app-config.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack": dial tcp 205.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: 
connect: connection refused
```

I can git clone this repository in VM properly.

I suspect there something wrong with network configuration of VM.
Network adapters:

1. NAT. Ports forwarded:

   - 8888 : 8080
   - 8443 : 443
   - 2222 : 22
2. Host only
3. Bridged

Firewall in VM is disabled.

Can someone please suggest what else can be a reason?
thanks

Comment: Is this with the ArgoCD UI? I has issues like this until I did it with the CLI so you might want to try that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have tried both for ssh accessed repositories, same result. For public https I have tried only UI, will try CLI as well, but expect the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The **"connection refused"** error typically means that the attempt to establish a connection to the specified IP address and port was unsuccessful.
If you're using HTTPS to clone the repository, try using **SSH** instead. **Change the repository URL to the SSH format** (git@gitlab.com:nanuchi/argocd-app-config.git) and see if it resolves the issue.